# Edit links in footer

Tags: entries

I'm new to Craft and need to add a link to the right side of the footer on this site http://britainthinks.com/

Can't see anything in the dashboard that holds the existing content or any obvious templates

There is a Global called footer but this doesn't have the links, just some contact info.

Would welcome any help!

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that because you seem unfamiliar with the templates for this site you inherited this project at some point? If you're using an IDE like PhpStorm (or even an editor like Atom or Sublime, I believe), you could do a "search in project" for `footer-container`, which should lead you to whatever twig template is handling your footer. From there you should be able to figure out what's going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible to be sure just by looking at the site. But there's a good chance the links are coded into the templates.

Again, the exact template could be anywhere. It's common to create a partial include it in a layout template but could equally just be within the layout template itself.

You don't say if this is Craft 2 or Craft 3 but you'll need to look in either `/craft/templates` for Craft 2 or `/templates` for Craft 3

You may also find you have an add on such as NavEE or A&M Nav installed. This allows the creation of navigation blocks which can be included in templates. So you might find the links in there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll check the templates again. It's on Craft 2

Comment: Most templates don't have any code after the main content section ends. There is one template which has '{% block footercode %}'

Comment: again, it's impossible to say really without seeing all the templates. I'd start by looking to see if there's a template named /index.twig or /index.html. Then look at the top of that for something like {% extends "_layout" %}  Then you want to find "_layout".

You might also look for directories named partials, includes or something like that and see if there's a template named footer or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will look into it further

Comment: Thanks for this help! I found the _layout.html file and the section to edit